# remove Nuke license expiration message - flexlm

Tags: nuke, flexlm

I have Nuke licenses installed on a flexLM server. The licenses are going to expire in a few days. When I start Nuke I get all the time this message "You have a temporary license for nuke on hostIDs [host] with 29 day(s) remaining." which it's annoying. Is there any flag in flexlm/Nuke to remove the worrying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `FN_DISABLE_LICENSE_DIALOG` to `1` to disable these messages in Nuke 8 and 9.

If you are using Nuke 7, the variable is named `FN_NUKE_DISABLE_TMPLIC_NOTIFY_DIALOG` instead, though this alternate variable will also work in Nuke 8 and 9.